# How to parse a string into no type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, csv

I am parsing a csv file:

```
    let lines = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    let headers = lines[0].split(',');
    for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
      let values = lines[i].split(',');
      let item = {};
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        item[headers[j]] = values[j];
      }
      items.push(item);
    }
    return items;
```

I am getting its data. However, the data are all strings. I want to pass them into JSON, and make them have no type, so I can pass them into variables with different types. I don't want to use parseInt/parseFloat directly, because I don't know the specific type of each variable.

However, each time I pass the values to JSON, they are all strings, e.x. "1234", not 1234. Normally I can pass JSON data to class without no type, but this time I convert the csvData into JSON, the JSON data are all strings. I guess it is because the split function makes it a string?

Optional:
I can pass the type into this function, like `readCsvFile<T>(csvData)`, can I do something like:

```
    if (typeof(T[headers[j]]) == 'number') {
      item[headers[j]] = parseFloat(values[j]);
    } else {
      item[headers[j]] = values[j];
    }
```

But T[header[j]] doesn't pass the compilation.

Comment: "because I don't know the specific type of each variable."

Well you need a way to find out, if it is a CSV then each column refers to a field which you know the type of.

Comment: I updated more details of the code. I have the way to know the type, but I want to make this function more generic.

Comment: So, what is the question? Javascript is typeless (and typescript is, too, since it's just a superset). If you don't want to cast them to any kind of type, just assign them, or cast them to string if you want them to all be strings. It would, however, make much more sense to follow @mpm's hint, since you still would need to parse them later.

Comment: @DanielGale Updated the question. It is the same type in each column. I can pass a generic class type in, how to check the type of each property?

Comment: @briosheje I thought it should be no type. However, when I pass the values into a class, all the types will be string, even if the property type is number.

Comment: @AuggieLi javascript has no clue whether the type you are importing is numeric or not. What I meant is that both typescript and javascript, at runtime, are typeless. Hence, you don't need to work with "no type" (defined as "any" in typescript), since they already will be such (either string, either any). I suggest you to follow mpm's idea, it's the cleverest and most solid solution, imho.

Comment: Just don't mix JSON and CSV... if you need a textual representation that natively parses to non-string types, just use JSON. If you need a table of values, use CSV. There should never be a situation where you don't know the types in each column of your table.

Comment: @briosheje If I pass the value into a class and not use parseInt/parseFloat, it is the type defaultly treated as string, even if the type of class property is number? I can pass JSON data to class without no type, but this time the JSON data are all strings.

Comment: @Patrick Robert Updated the question. Is it any way that I can make the csv into JSON, but the data have no string type. (as I mentioned in the question, this time the JSON data types are all strings)

Comment: @AuggieLi : Yes, if you explicitly tell typescript that a class's property is a number, at runtime, it just **does not matter**. It just WON'T cast it for you, it WON'T allow you to explicitly set the value in your code, but it **won't** prevent, at runtime, that this variable will not be the type declared. Remember: it's just a javascript superset, it won't do any magic for you, javascript **is** typeless, so typescript is (it's just "strong typed", not even at all. Besides, you can assign an "any" type to a "number" type).

Comment: @briosheje The issue is that the value parsed from csv are strings. I guess even I passed them into an 'any' variable, they will still be strings. Is it a way to convert these values to 'any' or unknown type?

Comment: @AuggieLi: No, there is no way to do such, because `any` is a generic type which indicates all the possible types. You can't explicitely cast to an "unknown" type, you can deal with unknown types, buy **can't** create an unknown type, because it just does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something more functional.

```
//Define variables
var csvData = "field1a,field2a,field3a\r\nfield1b,field2b,field3b";
var linesAsObjects = [];
var lines = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);

//Split fields here
var splitFields = function(line){
  let fields = line.split(',');
  addItem(fields);
}

// Assign field values to object or formatting here
var addItem = function(fields){
  let obj = {};
  obj.field1 = fields[0];
  obj.field2 = fields[1];
  obj.field3 = fields[2];

  linesAsObjects.push(obj);
}

// Call the code for each line
lines.forEach(splitFields);

//Printing lines and fields as assigned to an object.
console.log(linesAsObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to know the type (and you actually not trying to get the value of the property with the unknown type), then you can use the "unknown" type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html

This is far better than "any" and you can type the data at the point you need to get it.

Comment: I think this is the best solution to fix the issue. However, I am using Angular, which is not yet updated to Typescript 3.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use type any for the attributes.

```
// add the fields you have from the CSV
class ResultFromCSV {
  myValue: any;
  otherValue: any;
}

...
let lines = csvData.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    let headers = lines[0].split(',');
    for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
      let values = lines[i].split(',');

      // instantiate here
      let item = new ResultFromCSV();
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        item[headers[j]] = values[j];
      }
      items.push(item);
    }
    return items;
```

Comment: Is it anyway to make it generic, this function is like readCsvFile<T>(csvData)? The constructor of class could vary.

Comment: yes you can use something like that, check the typescript documentation, there are several examples there https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html